# How do I limit the number of git processes that GitLab starts?

Tags: gitlab

I have a continuous integration setup running on Jenkins where every time I push changes to a specific branch, Jenkins starts 50 EC2 slaves. Each slave checks out the branch and run some tests against the branch.

The problem is that the 50 EC2 slaves start all at once and they check out the branch from my GitLab server, which starts a git process for each slave and quickly runs out of memory (despite the fact that the server has 7.5GB of RAM.)

If I'm looking at top, I can see that as soon as the slaves get going, many git processes appear and start to quickly consume all the memory.  The kern.log tells me that the kernel has to periodically kill a git process because the system runs out of memory.

My question is how do I limit the number of git processes that GitLab starts in such a way that the slaves don't think GitLab has gone away.  (I'd like GitLab to put the requests in a queue and serve them 10 at a time, for example.)

I've also considered some other ideas. For example, I could make just a few of the slaves (seed slaves) pull the branch from GitLab and then have the rest of the slaves pull the branch from those seed slaves.  But that seems like it might involve some work.

Another idea is that I could stagger the EC2 launches by a few seconds, to spread the requests over a couple of minutes.  Or, I could get more memory.

I welcome ideas for any other approaches for dealing with this.

Comment: Were you running a CI runner on your main gitlab box?

Answer (score 0):

I think your last idea would be the best :
try to spread the load for your gitlab instance.

For example, you could start your CI by building the artifact :

Assuming you work with say java, you could build the war file on the CI server and distribute it through a shared S3 bucket.

This way, you query gitlab only once per build and run as many copies as you want. Each instance downloads the build and runs its tests.